# Can I use cross validation on a subset of the training set to select hyperparameters?

Tags: pca, cross-validation, train, hyperparameter

I am using R, and I had a dataset with 400000 rows and 800 columns, training a random forest model with only 100 trees on this dataset will take me about 1 and half hour on my laptop. So I went on and performed principal component analysis (PCA) on the dataset and find out that the first 100 PCs would retain approximately 92% of the variance. So I then train my model on the 100 PCs and the training time reduced to about 15 minutes. But it will still be very slow, if I want to select the optimal mtry value using 10 fold cross validation.

My question is, can I use only a smaller proportion of the training data, maybe 1/3 of it and use this smaller data set to select the mtry value via cross validation?

Comment: Yes, that's actually kind of the definition of cross validation. You can divide it into 3, and make 3 experiments, each time excluding one parts as test set, and using the other 2 as train. But I did not understand what you are trying to optimize. What is `mtry`?

Comment: @HalilPazarlama: `mtry` is no of variates sampled for each of the trees.

Comment: Also, think whether you really need the trees going all the way to nodesize 1 (or 5 for regression)? In my experience, larger nodes can save a lot of calculation time, often without much loss in predictive ability.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. But you'll almost always have a better result with more data.

There's not really a good theoretical framework to understand how much better it would be, or how much you'd likely gain from training on the whole set without actually trying it.

But if your accuracy is really important, then waiting another 90 minutes isn't the end of the world.

Whatever you do, make sure you shuffle the data such that you choose your subset randomly and that your resulting cross validation splits don't have any sampling bias - that would of course be a simple way that finding a hyperparameter by using a subset could be suboptimal.